# Undo changes in an arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, undo

I've an ArrayList of Line Objects called 'lines'. I made my own line class to draw lines with some constraints.  It involves selecting two points in a panel and a line is drawn connecting the two points.  Everytime a line is created, it is added to the 'lines'. The lines are drawn in a panel.

The paint function in my panel looks like this:

```
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g){      

       super.paintComponent(g);

       for(final Line r:lines){

            r.paint((Graphics2D)g);

       }
    }
```

And everytime two points are clicked on the panel, a new line is created.

```
class Board extends JPanel{

 public void placeLine(){
  Point p1,p2;
  JLabel l1,l2;
  ...
  lines.add(new Line(p1,p2,l1,l2));
  this.repaint();
 }
 public void deleteLine(Line l){
  lines.remove(l);
 }
}
```

I want to create an UndoAbleEdit in this, and everytime i give undo, the undo method must revert to the last action(i.e.creating a line or deleting a line). I've tried undo for events in JTextArea but i couldn't figure out how to build a custom undo for event changes in ArrayLists. Suggest an example for doing this.

And i'm really sorry for not posting it as an SSCCE.. It is a huge project and it is almost impossible to create an SSCCE.

Comment: does your deleteLine method work?

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583901/how-to-design-undo-redo-in-text-editor

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read about the Memento Pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern), then search the web for some code samples that use this pattern.

Comment: Yup.. Thanks!! But I've no idea about design patterns though.. Is there any way we can do this without using design patterns?

Comment: @SivaSubramaniam design patterns are basics to know. If you have never used them you should start to take a look at them.
(I'm sure you've used some of them but you didn't know if was is a design pattern.)

Comment: @SivaSubramaniam design patterns are a concept, an idea. Not an actual package to download and run. Think of it as best-practices for software development, as solutions to common software development problems. You need to read about the pattern and think about how to apply it to your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I would create and store Runnable objects for making undo changes in some stack structure, popping and running them as needed.
For your example:

```
class Board extends JPanel {
    ArrayList lines = new ArrayList();
    Stack<Runnable> undo = new Stack<Runnable>();

    public void placeLine() {
        Point p1, p2;
        JLabel l1, l2;


        final Line line = new Line(p1, p2, l1, l2);
        lines.add(line);
        undo.push(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                lines.remove(line);
                this.repaint();
            }
        });

        this.repaint();
    }

    public void deleteLine(final Line l) {
        lines.remove(l);
        undo.push(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                lines.add(l);
            }
        });
    }


    public void undo() {
        undo.pop().run();
    }
}
```